# How to write a key word for getting a css property in ROBOT frame work

Tags: robotframework

There is a user defined keyword called Get CSS property value (below is the keyword description)  but it only works for selenium library supporting locator but i need to rewrite for browser library supporting locator .. I am tried using get element keyword instead of get webelement it didn't worked .. could any one please help me this issue?

```
*** Keywords ***
Get CSS Property Value
    [Documentation]
    ...    Get the CSS property value of an Element.
    ...    
    ...    This keyword retrieves the CSS property value of an element. The element
    ...    is retrieved using the locator.
    ...    
    ...    Arguments:
    ...    - locator           (string)    any Selenium Library supported locator xpath/css/id etc.
    ...    - property_name     (string)    the name of the css property for which the value is returned.
    ...    
    ...    Returns             (string)    returns the string value of the given css attribute or fails.
    ...        
    [Arguments]    ${locator}    ${attribute name}
    ${css}=         Get WebElement    ${locator}
    ${prop_val}=    Call Method       ${css}    value_of_css_property    ${attribute name}
    [Return]     ${prop_val}
```

Comment: **value_of_css_property() element method** is Selenium Python method. I dont think it will work with playwright. Try to replace it

Comment: perhaps **Get Property** keyword from browser library is what you are looking for

Comment: I tried using Get Property It didn't worked .. @JiriJanous any other suggestion?

Comment: The browser library has a [get style](https://marketsquare.github.io/robotframework-browser/Browser.html#Get%20Style) keyword. Have you tried using it?

Comment: @Anisha can you show how you used the keyword. What exatly does it mean that it didnt work? What result did you get, and what are you expecting

Comment: I am trying to fetch the style from the below code .. I have used Get style, Get attribute, get element.... `<div class="navbar">
 <div id="shortkeyhelp" class="modal fade show" aria-labelledby="helpModalLabel" style="display:block;" role="dialog"> </div>
</div>   `           @JiriJanous

Comment: I have used get property too ... and the ERROR i am getting is        `TimeoutError: locator.elementHandle: Timeout 10000ms exceeded.
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector "//*[@id="shortkeyhelp"] >> nth=0" `                                 and I have tried using different selectors ..